# What are the advantages of using AWS Elastic Transcoder (for WAV to AAC) vs Lambda and ffmpeg?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transcoding, amazon-lambda

I did a price comparison between using Elastic Transcoder vs Lambda for WAV-to-AAC conversion. I have to say, AWS ET is significantly pricier than Lambda.

A 9-minute audio file transcoded using ET: $0.04
The same file transcoded on a 1536MB Lambda instance (33sec runtime, excluding free tier): $0.0000002 for the request, and $0.000825165 for the execution time.

Granted, the Lambda transcoding took 33 seconds, and the same job on ET took probably around a third of that. But the cost of ET just doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing something else here? I should add that these transcodings are user-invoked by an upload (similar to how SoundCloud takes uploaded audio and transcodes to MP3), I'm not sending batch jobs. So maybe ET isn't the right application for my use case.